# how to make a search engine using HTML

Tags: html, search-engine

i just got into HTML and want to make some sort of search engine.
is there a way to search the web from that page, OR redirect it to google or other search engine's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384276/how-do-i-create-a-search-engine-like-google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google's custom search engine (CSE) for this. It is really easy to setup. Go to the link given below.

https://www.google.com/cse/

You will get a code that you can paste to your webpage.